# Saving egrep output containing '*' to bash array

Tags: arrays, bash

I would like to save egrep output to a bash array:

```
arr=( $(egrep -Rn 'regex') )
```

If there so happens to be a '`*`' in the egrep result, it appears like bash is expanding the '`*`' to be all files in current directory.  And the expansion plus results of egrep are then saved into arr.

How do I fix this?  I want the '`*`' in the grep results to be unaltered.

Comment: Don't stick results into an array like this. It has exactly this (and other word-splitting issues). See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for how to properly (and safely) read line-by-line or field-by-field.

Comment: Alternatively, if you really just wanted to avoid the globbing you could turn globbing off with `set -f` (but this leaves the word-splitting issues/etc. affecting the assignment and isn't recommended as-such).

Comment: Okay, I'll look into your page.  But, I need to manipulate the results later, ask the user what he wants and continuing from there.  So I thought an array would be good for this?

Comment: I didn't say don't use an array. I said don't populate your array like this. See the linked page.

Comment: Hmm. Shame this doesn't have an entry on the BashPitfalls page (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls), being as common of a mistake as it is.

Comment: Okay, great.  Thanks for the page.  I've been trying to find your page forever!  When I usually do a search I don't often find it.  But, when I do a bash FAQ it's right there on the top.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the idiom attempted in the question "correctly" might look something like this:

```
# DON'T DO THIS.

set -f         # turn off globbing
IFS=$'\n'      # word-split only on newlines
arr=( $(...) ) # populate array
unset IFS      # return IFS to defaults (assuming it was there before)
set +f         # turn globbing back on
```

Obviously, there's a lot of room to get this wrong and leave your shell in a state other than the way it started (What if your script had a different initial IFS value? What if this code is sourced from a script that wants globbing to be disabled to work correctly?). Don't do it.

---

One approach, compatible with bash 3.x, is to use `read -a` (reading into an array) with `IFS` (used to separate fields) containing a newline, and `-d` (used to separate records) set to a NUL:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a arr < <(egrep -Rn 'regex' && printf '\0')
```

The trailing `NUL` added to the input is present to ensure that `read` exits successfully; otherwise, this could trigger an abrupt exit if using `set -e`.

---

A longer but more explicit approach is to do the iteration yourself:

```
arr=( )
while IFS= read -r; do
  arr+=( "$REPLY" )
done < <(egrep -Rn 'regex')
```

---

Another, using bash 4.x features ([readarray, AKA mapfile](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/mapfile)):

```
readarray -t arr < <(egrep -Rn 'regex')
```

Comment: Hey this is cool.  Thanks!  I'm using bash 4.x.  So the last thing works great.  Can you explain to me what does the '< <' mean?  Or what is it called so I can read about it?  I see you had to run the egrep in a subshell instead of say $(...)?  Is there a reason for this?  Thanks.

Comment: It's not `< <` that means anything. `<` means a thing, and `<()` means another thing, and they can be used together. :)

Comment: ...and by the way, `$(...)` is also a subshell. `<()` is process substitution.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution, or http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst